# Isolate the call to a function

Tags: x86-64, assembly

Is it possible to call a function of a binary and obtain its result (without calling other functions), to isolate; are there any tools to do this?

Comment: Is the binary a dynamically-linked ELF?

Comment: Yes it's a dynamically-linked ELF @julian

Comment: Then you can use LIEF as mentioned below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ida's [Appcall](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_appcall.pdf) functionality:

> Appcall is a mechanism to call functions inside the debugged program
>   from the debugger or your script as if it were a built-in function.
>   Such a mechanism can be used for debugging, fuzzing and testing
>   applications. Appcall mechanism highly depends on the type information
>   of the function to be called. For that reason it is necessary to have
>   a correct function prototype before doing an Appcall, otherwise
>   different or incorrect results may be returned.

If it's an elf and you don't have Ida, [LIEF](https://lief.quarkslab.com) is a good option. You can see a tutorial to export an internal function and call it [here](https://lief.quarkslab.com/doc/latest/tutorials/08_elf_bin2lib.html)